# how to permanently change the grub default boot path

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I was trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows (windows was preinstalled). Then I screwed up by overwriting the boot path of windows with GRUB. So now every time I start the computer it will go into the GRUB command line first.

I can enter Windows still by entering:

```
root=(hd0,1)
chainloader --force +1
boot
```

However, I still have to type in those commands every time. GRUB doesn't recognize commands like `save default` or `makeactive`

More importantly, I can't boot from the USB which contains my Linux at all now. When I select boot from usb drive, I just get a black screen. I can discard Windows if necessary to install Ubuntu. But now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by using boot-repair https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/.
Burn this into a disk/usb, boot it from there, and it'll automatically repair the boot problems. 
Then just restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you have this solution too:

[Rescatux rescuing broken GNU/Linux and Windows installations and boot loaders](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)

Download the ".iso" format file and install it on a USB flash drive by typing this command in the terminal (Replace source and destination in the command):

```
dd bs=4M if=/link/to/my-distribution.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync
```